# Rust lifetime inference for struct methods

Tags: methods, struct, rust, reference, lifetime

This code is based on the example code in the Rust book in the lifetimes chapter. I was wondering how do the following two versions of the same method differ:

```
struct Important<'a> {
    part: &'a str,
}

impl<'a> Important<'a> {
    fn larger<'b>(&'b self, other: &'b str) -> &'b str {
        if self.part.len() > other.len() {
            self.part
        } else {
            other
        }
    }
}
```

versus

```
struct Important<'a> {
    part: &'a str,
}

impl<'a> Important<'a> {
    fn larger(&self, other: &'a str) -> &str {
        if self.part.len() > other.len() {
            self.part
        } else {
            other
        }
    }
}
```

I guess in the first version we are instructing the compiler that

1. Find a lifetime `'b` such that both `&self` and the reference `other` are valid during it (probably the shorter of the two lifetimes if they overlap)
2. Make sure that the returned reference is only used within that lifetime `'b` because outside it might become a dangling reference.

What does the second version of the code do? One of the lifetime elision rules in the Rust book says that in a struct method the returned reference is assigned the lifetime of the `&self` parameter (which is `'a` here), so are we saying that `other` should also be valid for the same lifetime as the `&self` parameter, which is the lifetime `'a`?

Semantically, is this the same code or could these versions behave differently depending of the lifetimes of `other` and the struct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What does the second version of the code do? One of the lifetime elision rules in the rust book says that in a struct method the returned reference is assigned the lifetime of the &self parameter (which is `'a` here), so are we saying that other should also be valid for the same lifetime as the `&self` parameter, which is the lifetime `'a`?

That's slightly inaccurate, the lifetime of `&self` in the second example *is not* `'a` but it is *bounded by* `'a`. The second example would desugar to this if we expand it by reversing Rust's lifetime elision rules:

```rust
struct Important<'a> {
    part: &'a str,
}

impl<'a> Important<'a> {
    fn larger<'b>(self: &'b Important<'a>, other: &'a str) -> &'b str {
        if self.part.len() > other.len() {
            self.part
        } else {
            other
        }
    }
}
```

The reason why self is bounded by `'a` is because `&'b Important<'a>` implies `'b: 'a` or in plain terms *"`'a` outlives `'b`"* which must be true otherwise the reference may get invalidated. If we expand the first example the type of `self` again becomes `&'b Important<'a>`. The only difference between the first and second example is the type of `other`, in the first it's `&'b str` and in the second it's `&'a str` but that's an irrelevant detail since the return value has the type `&'b str` which is constrained by the `'b` lifetime and we know that `'b: 'a` so functionally both examples are the same.

Comment: I think 'b:'a means  'b outlives 'a?  https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/trait-bounds.html#lifetime-bounds